# SQL Hotel Booking System

Tags: sql

I'm having a bit of trouble with a hotel bookings system. I can't determine which rooms are available at which dates. I'll simplify the tables here so you can get the jist of what I'm trying to do.

```
Table 1 (ROOMS) :
RoomID,
RoomType (Single, Double etc)

Table 2 (BOOKINGS)
BookingID,
RoomID,
Available (Yes/No),
CheckInDate,
CheckOutDate,
RoomType
```

I'm trying to search the `BOOKINGS` table for an available `room(ID)` depending on `checkin, checkout and roomtype`. Obviously I can't search it for this because there's nothing in there at the moment and even if there was, it would be list of all the rooms that aren't available (Current bookings) so I thought that I could compare the `ROOMS` table and `BOOKINGS` table like this and try to get a vacant room(ID) this way.

```
SELECT RoomID FROM ROOMS 
WHERE RoomType = 'Single' AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT RoomID FROM BOOKINGS WHERE CheckOut >= '2013-12-02'
AND CheckIn <= '2013-12-07')
AND RoomType = 'Single' 
AND Available = 'Yes')
```

This is returning all the single rooms in the ROOMS table.

EXAMPLE: A booking is made for a single room (Number 1) for the dates 2013-12-01 until 2013-12-08. If I try to make a booking with the current logic for 2013-12-02 until 2013-12-07, it returns that room number 1 is available. Anyone have an idea on how to do this? Something simple as possible preferred.

I've used a simplified naming convention here just to make it more readable.

Comment: Why are you keeping RoomType in both tables? Seems like something which belongs purely to the Room relation and has nothing to do with bookings.

Comment: Because I'll have to filter results based on RoomType and the checkin/out dates to find an available room.

Comment: Why? You already have RoomID, why do you need to filter on RoomType?

Comment: I may miss something after a quick glance but could it be that your `NOT EXISTS` and the CheckIn/CheckOut date comparison are crossed? Also shouldn't `Available` be `No` if you want to exclude the room?

Comment: Can you tell me how it would work without RoomType then?

Comment: @user3041664 You already filter on the RoomType in your outer query - there's no point in keeping this attribute with the booking. If you need to query the RoomType when looking at a Booking you can JOIN on the RoomID.

Comment: @user3041664 Did you try changing `NOT EXISTS` into `EXISTS` to make it consitent with your subquery which obviously looks for available rooms?

Comment: Couple of things: (1) are the datatypes on your date columns actually 'date' or 'datetime's? you must be careful when comparing these and (2) do you need to store availability in the 'Available' column - couldn't we assume the room is unavailable if there is a record in BOOKINGS, and available if there is no record?

Answer (score 0):

You need to correlate your subquery.
Currently there is nothing relating the EXISTS subquery with the outer query on ROOMS.
So you will either get ALL single rooms or NONE, depending on whether the EXISTS is true or false when run independently.

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT RoomID FROM ROOMS R
WHERE RoomType = 'Single' AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM BOOKINGS 
 WHERE RoomID = R.RoomID
    AND CheckOutDate >= '2013-02-02'
    AND CheckInDate <= '2013-02-07'
)
```

I made a SQLFiddle example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0ff3/6

Comment: And of course, making this fast is on of the reasons why hotel systems don't tend to be awfully cheap :)